# How do I truncate a value to a certain number of decimal places?

Tags: c#, floating-point

I have to use this:

```
double trunc(double nummber, int position);
```

and my program should give the double `nummber` minus the position value, like this:

```
Console.Write(trunc(3.14159,2));  // 3.14
```

How can I write it ?

Comment: Are you just trying to only show x number of decimal places?

Comment: Is this homework (if it is, please include that in the post)?  Have you been assigned to write a `Truncate` function?  By the way, by convention, public method names start with a capital letter in C# (they don't have to, but that's the expectation).

Comment: `Math.Round(3.14159,2)`

Comment: Have you looked at `Math.Truncate`.  If you combine that with a pre-multiplication and a post divide by a power of 10, you probably have a solution.

Comment: @Bidou Rounding != Truncation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way that works.  You can do it for `double` as I did, or `decimal` (or both).  I calculated the "multiplier" by hand, since I suspect a small number of integer multiplications would be faster than using Math.Pow.  But, to each their own:

```
 public static double Truncate(double value, int decimalPlaces)
 {
     var multiplier = 1;
     for (var i = 0; i < decimalPlaces; ++i)
     {
         multiplier *= 10;       //this makes sense if integer multiplication is faster than Math.Pow(), if not...
     }

     return Math.Truncate(multiplier * value) / multiplier;
 }
```

You probably also want to put in a check that the `decimalPlaces` integer is non-negative and no larger than 9 (otherwise, it will overflow an `int`).  If you want more than 9 digits, you'll want to make `multiplier` a `long`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I didnt know that an int bigger than 9 should be long instead. Thank you again

Comment: An integer can hold a little more +/- 2 billion (that's 2,000,000,000).  That has 9 zeros.  I'm multiplying by 10 to the `decimalPlaces`, so if `decimalPlaces` gets too big, `multiplier` will overflow

Comment: @ahmet: If you are going to do this a lot, create an `int` (or `long`) array of possible mulitpliers and just pull in the right value as you need it (rather than calculating it each time).  If you do this on the fly (which doesn't make any sense here), it's called _memorization_ (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to *round* up to `2` decimal points: `f2` formatting string is enough

```
Console.Write($"{3.14159:f2}");
```

If you want to *truncate* up to `2` decimal points: we have to scale up (`* 100`) truncate to integer and scale back (`/ 100`). Finally, `f2` formatting in case we have round up errors (say, `3.13999999`)

```
Console.Write($"{Math.Truncate(3.14159 * 100) / 100:f2}");
```

The same idea (scaling, truncate, scaling back) if you want to implement `trunc`:

```
static double trunc(double nummber, int position) {
  return Math.Truncate(nummber * Math.Pow(10.0, position)) / Math.Pow(10.0, position);
}
```

Comment: I actually want the user to decide how much to trunc. I thought about doing a ReadLine function for int position and double number. The console will give me the number in the trunced form back.